# Can I use present tense instead of present continuous tense in the following sentence?

Tags: present-tense, present-continuous

Q:
I heard you started a new job. __________ (enjoy) it?

The correct answer is *are you enjoying it*.(Page 3, intermediate grammar in use)

I wonder if *do you enjoy it* is also a correct answer. It sounds just right to my (albeit non-native) ears.

Comment: The continuous verb form is "licensed / encouraged" by the fact that *you **recently started** a **new** job*, which implicitly calls attention to the ***duration*** of your (new) employment. If the preceding sentence had been, say, *I hear you work in local government* (with ***no*** explicit reference to any particular "length of service"), you'd be far less likely to use the continuous verb form in the follow-up question. But for your *exact* context, both versions are fine - it's just a matter of what *nuance* you want to attach to the question.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yes, you are broadly right.  It is so in virtue of the initial statement, which, as you say, suggests that the recipient of the question has only just started.  So (it might be worth adding) we are given to understand that it is too recent to make the enjoyment (if enjoyment there has been) well enough established to allow the plain present tense.  Also, I do not know whether this observation is a British versus American English thing, but "I heard you started " sounds like an Americanism, where the British would say "I hear you've started".

Comment: Wouldn't we usually say either "I hear you've started" or "I heard you'd started?" "I heard you started a new job" suggests the speaker is going to say "and then blew it."

Comment: OK. Ignore me. Tuffy's covered that!

Comment: The second version sounds fine to me. I doubt any native speaker would consider either version unusual or out of place.

Comment: @Tuffy: I'd be surprised if the *I heard you started / I hear you've started* distinction was particularly dependent on which side of the pond the speaker hails from. From my perspective, it's just that I'd be more likely to use the first form if that new job (and/or me hearing about it) was some time in the past, and/or the actual *starting* was currently of interest to me. For example, if my follow-up question was ***Did** you have to attend an interview?* rather than *How **are** you finding the workload?*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers That is a good illustration of how a language evolves and the inevitable small differences between the speech habits of different speakers.

Answer (score 1):

"Are you liking it?" and "Are you enjoying it?" are somewhat odd constructs because they imply an active, incomplete action; you either like something or you don't. But this is very common and certainly not incorrect. To my American ears, "Are you enjoying it?" has a slight overtone that implies "... so far?" -- recognizing that the person's opinion is based on a limited time and could change. "Do you enjoy it?" is a bit more permanent. But the listener would reply the same way to either question.

Answer (score 1):

1. "Do you enjoy it?" is not an incorrect usage.
2. The slight difference in connotation is similar, I think, to the Spanish verbs *ser* and *estar*. Both are translated in English as "to be," but *ser* conveys a permanent, identity-based state of being ("I am a doctor") while *estar* conveys a temporary, transient state ("I am hungry"). The question in your example is one of many ways that one can make small-talk, inquiring into someone's immediate state with continuous tense: "How are you doing? What's happening? How are you feeling?"